# Beautifulsoup 4: How to find immediate previous sibling

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following text in an xml-file:

```
     <div><head facs="#facs_29_TextRegion_1624461408183_2024">
        <lb facs="#facs_29_r2l33" n="N001"/><supplied reason="article_added">11</supplied> Von dem Gewalt und Auctoritet
           <lb facs="#facs_29_r2l34" n="N002"/>der Kirchen.</head>
        <p facs="#facs_30_TextRegion_1624462119791_2191">
           <pb facs="#facs_30" xml:id="img_0030" n="13r"/>
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l3" n="N001"/>Wiewol die schrifft, wie <rs type="person" ref="#jesus">Christus</rs> sagt, nit <w>auff<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>gelößt</w> werden kan<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Io_10,35">Joh 10,35</ref>.</note> und also deßhalben <w>unbe<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>weglich</w> und grösser dann aller menschen <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>walt</w>, So ist doch bei der Kirchen allweg die
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l8" n="N005"/>macht gewesen, die waren schrifften von der falschen <w>zu<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>scheyden</w>. Daher kumpt der Canon der schrifft, dardurch
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l10" n="N007"/>die rechten von den ungerechten schrifften, welche under
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l11" n="N008"/>dem namen der Aposteln des Herrn unnd irer Jünger
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l12" n="N009"/>eingefürt, underscheyden worden sein.
        </p>
        <p facs="#facs_30_TextRegion_1624462217347_2208">
           <lb facs="#facs_30_line_1624462119963_2193" n="N001"/>Und eben wie die Kirchen diser ding halben <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>walt</w> und macht allwegen gehabt, Also hat sie auch <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>walt</w>, die schrifft außzulegen und sonderlich auß inen die
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l16" n="N004"/>lehren zunemen unnd zuerklären, Seitemal der Heylig
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l17" n="N005"/>Geyst bei ir ist unnd leyttet sie inn aller warheyt, wie
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l18" n="N006"/>dann der Herr <rs type="person" ref="#jesus">Christus</rs> solches selbs zugesagt hat.<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Io_16,13">Joh 16,13</ref>.</note> <w>Da<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/><note place="margin-right" facs="#facs_30_TextRegion_1624463212314_2472">
              <lb/>2. Petri 1.</note>her</w> spricht Sant <rs type="person" ref="#simon_petrus">Peter</rs>: <!--from here --><q>Alle weissagung der schrifft <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>schicht</w> nicht auß eygner außlegung, sonder die Heyligen
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l21" n="N009"/>menschen, mit dem Heyligen Geyst erfüllet, haben also <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>redt</w>.</q><!-- to here --><note type="annotation"><ref type="biblical" cRef="2Pt_1,20-21">2 Petr 1,20f.</ref></note> Und dise macht, dise schrifft außzulegen, ist sonderlich
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l23" n="N011"/>noth inn den stücken, die schwer seindt zuverstehn, wie es
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l24" n="N012"/>dann die that an ir selbst weiset.
        </p> 
 <p facs="#facs_27_TextRegion_1623939741655_266">
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l6" n="N001"/>Nun seind inn diser Kirchen nit allein die heiligen,
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l7" n="N002"/>sonder auch die bösen als glider desselbigen, wiewol <w>un<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>fruchtbar</w>. Daher der Herr <rs type="person" ref="#jesus">Christus</rs> sie jetzt vergleicht <w>ei<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>nem</w> netze, das man ins Meer würfft, welches gute unnd
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l10" n="N005"/>böse visch ergreifft;<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Mt_13,47-48">Mt 13,47-48</ref>.</note> Bald hernach vergleicht er sie einem
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l11" n="N006"/>acker, der zu gleich mit gutem samen beseet ist und tregt
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l12" n="N007"/>doch unkraut.<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Mt_13,24-26">Mt 13,24-26</ref>.</note> Dann die durch die Tauff glider der <w>Kir<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>chen</w> worden seind, fallen offt wider inn sünde und machen
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l14" n="N009"/>sich knecht der sünden unnd schuldig der ewigen <w>verdam<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>nuß</w>; und wiewol sie die gnad der gemeinschafft der <w>heyli<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>gen</w> und der Geistlichen Kirchen verlieren, so bleiben sie
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l17" n="N012"/>doch gleich wol inn der eüsserlichen gesellschafft der <w>Chri<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>sten</w> und der Kirchen: Sie hören das wort Gottes, <w>gebrau<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>chen</w> die Sacrament unnd haben alle eüsserliche ding mit
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l20" n="N015"/>der Kirchen gemein, es were dann, das sie durch ein <w>recht<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>messige</w> Excommunication oder durch ein Schisma oder
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l22" n="N017"/>durch Ketzerey oder abfal vom Christlichen glauben <w>ab<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>geschnitten</w> wurden.
            </p>
</div>
```

and I make the soup like this:

```
with open(f'interim2.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()   
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')
Refs = soup.select('ref[cRef]')

data = []
for ref in Refs:
    if ref.get('cref').split('_')[0] in AT:
        data.append((ref.get('cref') , 'at', ref.getText() , ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q')))
    else:
        data.append((ref.get('cref') , 'nt', ref.getText() , ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q')))

    #die nun gefüllte Liste wird zum pd.DataFrame (df_data) konvertiert und die Spaltenbezeichnungen angepasst
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_data.columns = ['kuerzel', 'atnt', 'stelle', 'zitat']
```

where I think the find_previous_sibling is not doing what I want it to do.
It detects the first previous `<q>`, which is not always what I want. The `<ref type="biblical" cRef="{cRef}"/>` is always the child of a `<note>`. If it is a verbatim bible quote (let's not discuss the concept of verbatim in early modern texts), the  as an immediate sibling that is, according to our rules always a `<q>`.
My code returns any first occurrence before the `ref` in question, I however need the **immediate** sibling of the parent(`<note>`) to be a `<q>`.

Is there a function that I am missing?
All the best,

Edit for clarifiaction:
with this code, I get a list of all elements that I want to have for the `ref.parent.find_previous_sibling("q")` in my code.

```
qs = []
for ref in Refs:
    if ref.parent.previous_sibling == ref.parent.find_previous_sibling("q"):
        qs.append(ref.parent.find_previous_sibling("q"))
```

edit2: added another paragrap to the example, where the case that `<q>...</q><note type="annotation><ref type="biblical" cRef="{cRef}"> ..</ref></note>` is not met. Sometimes, the immediate sibling to the note is a q, but not always. If the immediate sibling is a q, I want only the text, without any tags inside, else I'd like to have "not a direct quote"
my current code:

```
with open(f'interim2.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()   
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')
Refs = soup.select('ref[cRef]')

data = []
for ref in Refs:
    if ref.get('cref').split('_')[0] in AT:
        for ref in Refs:
            if ref.parent.previous_sibling == ref.parent.find_previous_sibling("q"):
                data.append((ref.get('cref') , 'at', ref.getText() , ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q')))
            else:
                data.append((ref.get('cref') , 'at', ref.getText() , 'not a direct quote'))
    else:
        for ref in Refs:
            if ref.parent.previous_sibling == ref.parent.find_previous_sibling("q"):
                data.append((ref.get('cref') , 'at', ref.getText() , ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q')))
            else:
                data.append((ref.get('cref') , 'at', ref.getText() , 'not a direct quote'))
```

Comment: Okay got your comment to the `<q>` but it is hard to follow, there is no `qs = []` in your code as mentioned in your edit. However `ref.parent.find_previous_sibling("q")` gives you the immediate previous sibling `<q>`  -- `<q>Alle weissagung der schrifft ... eygner außlegung, sonder die Heyligen
          <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l21" n="N009"></lb>menschen, mit dem Heyligen Geyst erfüllet, haben also <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
   <lb></lb>redt</w>.</q>` While `ref.parent.previous_sibling` will give you any but this must not be a `<p>` *May provide a more focused example, that deals with the issue*

Comment: gave some clarifications: I added another paragraph in the xml, so that the "other condition" (indicated by Vgl.) also appears in my example. 
Furthermore, I added the function to obtain direct quotes (the list qs). 
My remaining goal is to identify how many characters other than tags and white spaces are inside of all qs. 
(at least I think that's the remaining challenge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use and compare this way:

```
ref.parent.find_previous_sibling() == ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q')
```

> In real documents, the .next_sibling or .previous_sibling of a tag
> will usually be a string containing whitespace.

So `.previous_sibling` is not the same as `find_previous_sibling()` that you should use instead to get your goal.

```
ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q').get_text(' ',strip=True) if ref.parent.find_previous_sibling() == ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q') else 'not a direct quote'
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = '''
<div><head facs="#facs_29_TextRegion_1624461408183_2024">
        <lb facs="#facs_29_r2l33" n="N001"/><supplied reason="article_added">11</supplied> Von dem Gewalt und Auctoritet
           <lb facs="#facs_29_r2l34" n="N002"/>der Kirchen.</head>
        <p facs="#facs_30_TextRegion_1624462119791_2191"> some text</p>
        <p facs="#facs_30_TextRegion_1624462217347_2208">
           Some more text
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l18" n="N006"/>dann der Herr <rs type="person" ref="#jesus">Christus</rs> solches selbs zugesagt hat.<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Io_16,13">Joh 16,13</ref>.</note> <w>Da<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/><note place="margin-right" facs="#facs_30_TextRegion_1624463212314_2472">
              <lb/>2. Petri 1.</note>her</w> spricht Sant <rs type="person" ref="#simon_petrus">Peter</rs>: <q>Alle weissagung der schrifft <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>schicht</w> nicht auß eygner außlegung, sonder die Heyligen
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l21" n="N009"/>menschen, mit dem Heyligen Geyst erfüllet, haben also <w>ge<pc>-</pc>
           <lb/>redt</w>.</q><note type="annotation"><ref type="biblical" cRef="2Pt_1,20-21">2 Petr 1,20f.</ref></note> Und dise macht, dise schrifft außzulegen, ist sonderlich
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l23" n="N011"/>noth inn den stücken, die schwer seindt zuverstehn, wie es
           <lb facs="#facs_30_r1l24" n="N012"/>dann die that an ir selbst weiset.
        </p>
 <p facs="#facs_27_TextRegion_1623939741655_266">
               Some more text
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l10" n="N005"/>böse visch ergreifft;<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Mt_13,47-48">Mt 13,47-48</ref>.</note> Bald hernach vergleicht er sie einem
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l11" n="N006"/>acker, der zu gleich mit gutem samen beseet ist und tregt
               <lb facs="#facs_27_r1l12" n="N007"/>doch unkraut.<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Mt_13,24-26">Mt 13,24-26</ref>.</note> Dann die durch die Tauff glider der <w>Kir<pc>-</pc>
               <lb/>chen</w> worden seind, fallen offt wider inn sünde und machen
            </p>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(example)

Refs =soup.select('ref[cRef]')

data = []
for ref in Refs:
    data.append((
        ref.get('cref') , 
        'at', 
        ref.getText() , 
        ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q').get_text(' ',strip=True) if ref.parent.find_previous_sibling() == ref.parent.find_previous_sibling('q') else 'not a direct quote'
    ))
data
```

##### Output

```
[('Io_16,13', 'at', 'Joh 16,13', 'not a direct quote'),
 ('2Pt_1,20-21',
  'at',
  '2 Petr 1,20f.',
  'Alle weissagung der schrifft ge - schicht nicht auß eygner außlegung, sonder die Heyligen menschen, mit dem Heyligen Geyst erfüllet, haben also ge - redt .'),
 ('Mt_13,47-48', 'at', 'Mt 13,47-48', 'not a direct quote'),
 ('Mt_13,24-26', 'at', 'Mt 13,24-26', 'not a direct quote')]
```

Comment: I am going from <ref> to the parent with 'ref.parent' aren't I? 
so there I am at the note. some <note> have a direct sibling <q> , as indicated by my <!-- from here --> <!-- to here --> comment in the XML snippet.
Unfortunately, I am really looking for the immediate sibling of the <note> at the bottom of the snippet, that not all <note> elements might have

Comment: this seems to do the trick. My calculating function seems a little broken now. 
I want to add all characters from <q> unless the zitat says 'not a direct quote' ... I'll figure this out, I think :-D